# Fdisk is showing different disk size than that of lsblk output

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos-7

Why is disk sizing different on fdisk and lsblk in CentOS? I am working on script which will do dynamic partition and by getting Total Size with these commands will not help

```
lsblk /dev/sda | awk '/da / {print $4}'
> 477G

fdisk -l | grep Disk
> Disk /dev/sda: 512.1 GB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fdisk shows the size in SI (decimal) units, where 1 GB = 1*1000*1000*1000 B = 10<sup>9</sup> B.

lsblk shows the size in IEC (binary) units, where 1 **GiB** = 1*1024*1024*1024 B = 2<sup>30</sup> B.

In your case, 512 GB = 512000000000 B ≈ 476.8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 B ≈ 476.8 GiB.

Comment: I was getting free size with lsblk and doing partition with parted due to which i was getting mismatch. Now i am getting total size with this command and its working as expectations 
TOTAL=`parted -s /dev/sda print free | grep Free | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: Why not use `lsblk --bytes`?